# Error al ejecutar jhipster --blueprints dotnetcore

Tags: dotnetcore, jhipster

Cuando voy a ejecutar el comando: `jhipster --blueprints dotnetcore`

me genera el siguiente error:

```
INFO! Switching to JHipster installed locally in current project's node repository (node_modules)
INFO! Using bundled JHipster
INFO! No custom sharedOptions found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-dotnetcore at /home/diego/Proyects/jhipster/App01/node_modules/generator-jhipster-dotnetcore
INFO! No custom commands found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-dotnetcore at /home/diego/Proyects/jhipster/App01/node_modules/generator-jhipster-dotnetcore
ERROR! Package subpath './generators/app' is not defined by "exports" in /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-dotnetcore/node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './generators/app' is not defined by "exports" in /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-dotnetcore/node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-dotnetcore/generators/app/index.js:3:22) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

Comment: Hhola pudiste resolver el problema?